# Magento 2. In which database table is catalogsearch_fulltext index saved?

Tags: magento2, table, index

In which table is information produced by **catalogsearch_fulltext** **index** saved when SQL is set as a search engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the table is **catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1**

Answer (score 0):

Some additional details from Mysql perspectivne :

eav_attribute : here you can check your attribute ID.

catalog_eav_attribute : is attribute searchable or not : is_searchable

catalog_product_entity_varchar  : Here you can find your attribute if the data type for attribute was varchar.

catalogsearch_fulltext_scope28  : here 28 is store id

Sql query : SELECT * FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope28` WHERE `data_index` LIKE 'apple' LIMIT 50

Probably this will give more insight.